# Mastercard not being accepted on GCP

Tags: kubernetes

I just started to use Google Cloud platform for Kubernetes and I am trying to confirm my MasterCard details in order to get started with the free-trial but it gets rejected every time.

I tried contacting google support and searching online for similar issues and solutions but all to no avail.

Please how do I go around this?

Comment: This is a community web site. We can't help you with vendor billing issues. You need to contact the vendor.

Comment: You probably experienced a wide spread glitch with GCP billing... they sent apology emails and it was all over twitter. https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ads-outage-causing-billing-confusion-32141.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best answer for your question you can find in the [official Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing):

> ## Cloud Billing Support
>
> All Google Cloud accounts get free billing and payments support. This
> page tells you how to contact Cloud Billing Support if you need help
> with your Cloud Billing account, and shows you where to get more
> information about managing your billing account.
>
> Cloud Billing Support is available in several regions and languages.
> For information about support availability, see  [Google Cloud Support
> Plans](https://cloud.google.com/support).

As you can read above ***"All Google Cloud accounts get free billing and payments support."***

As mentioned in comments by @Michael Hampton, this is a type of issue that cannot be resolved by **Open Source Community** and recommended action should be contacting the vendor's support.

They even provide direct link for contacting **Cloud Billing Support**:

> ### How to contact Cloud Billing Support
>
> #### For Billing Administrators
>
> For Cloud Billing accounts you own, follow this link to contact Cloud
> Billing Support. Note that  **you must be a billing administrator**
> on at least one Cloud Billing account to use this contact method.
>
> [Contact Cloud Billing
> Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat?_ga=2.6149747.1754600463.1598268006-977490916.1598268006)

Btw. they do support **MasterCard** as you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods):

> We accept **debit cards with the Visa or MasterCard logo**.

So you should be able to further clarify with them what can be the issue in your particular case.